# Can we prove the divergence of $S=\frac{1}2+\frac{1}3+\frac{1}5+\frac{1}7+\frac{1}{11}\cdots$ like this?

Tags: sequences-and-series, proof-verification, prime-numbers, alternative-proof, divergent-series

We know that $\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{5}+\cdots$ diverges.

So, $T=\frac{1}{n.2}+\frac{1}{n.3}+\frac{1}{n.4}+\frac{1}{n.5}+\cdots$=$\frac{1}{n}$$(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{5}+\cdots)$ diverges too for any natural number $n$.

Now, we can easily show that $S>T$ since $n$ can take greater value than the difference between the denominators of any two consecutive terms of $S$.

Therefore, $S$ diverges too.

---

**EDIT:** $S$ is the sum of the reciprocals of the primes.

---

**EDIT 2:** $n$ can take any natural numbered value greater than the largest distance between any two consecutive primes.

Comment: "Now, we can easily show that $S>T$...". You might find that easy, but not me.

Comment: Could you elaborate on this OP?

Comment: See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divergence_of_the_sum_of_the_reciprocals_of_the_primes

Comment: I don't expect $S>T$ for any $n$.  With $N$ terms, $T$ grows like $\ln(N)$, while $S$ grows like $\ln\big(\ln(N)\big)$.

Comment: @Peter I did saw an outline of all the proofs there before posting my question but I didn't saw anything related to the proof posted here. Is there anything specific I should look in the link?

Comment: What precisely is $n $?

Comment: @ankit  From the Prime Number Theorem, the $N$-th prime $p_N$ is approximately $N\,\ln(N)$, and $$\int\limits_1^N\,\frac{1}{x\,\ln(x)}\,\text{d}x=\ln\big(\ln(N)\big)\,.$$

Comment: There are arbitrary large prime gaps, so "$n$ can take any natural numbered value greater than the largest distance between any two consecutive primes" doesn't work.

Comment: I think the idea behind this is a bit different from that what was discussed here. The OP should have considered the *partial* sums $S_N$ up to some $N$'th reciprocal prime $p_N$ and $n=\max(\text{primegaps}(N))$ and then let $N\to \infty$. I'm lazy to write out the formulae - and possibly this still leads to nothing, it's just an impulse...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your proof is not correct.  You say:

> $n$ can take greater value than the difference between the denominators of any two consecutive terms of $S$

It is true that if $p_1,p_2$ are two consecutive terms of $S$ (i.e., two consecutive primes) then we can find some $n$ such that $n>p_2-p_1$.  However, in order to use this to show that $S$ diverges, we would need to find an $n$ such that $n>q_2-q_1$ *for all* pairs of consecutive primes $q_1,q_2$.

This is impossible.  Indeed, for any $n$, the numbers $n!+2,n!+3,\dots,n!+n$ are not prime and so there must be a pair of consecutive primes that differ by at least $n$.

---

If your claim were true, then the sequence $S$ would diverge at least as quickly as any sequence $T_n$.  But we know this to be untrue: the harmonic series diverges like $\log(n)$, while the sum of the reciprocals of the primes diverges like $\log(\log(n))$.

Comment: If we substitute $n$ by $n!$ in $T$ then?

Comment: @ankit Then it makes no difference: there are two consecutive primes $p_1,p_2$ such that $p_2-p_1>n!$.

Comment: Can we hope to prove an upper bound on the distance between consecutive primes one day or is it the case(proven?) that the distance between two consecutive primes can be arbitrarily large?

Comment: @ankit Why are you insisting on finding this upper bound when multiple people keep telling you that there is no such thing.  The gap between two consecutive primes can be arbitrarily large.

Comment: @ankit I answered this in my answer.  Let $n$ be any number.  We can prove that there are consecutive primes with distance at least $n$.  Indeed, let $p_1$ be the largest prime smaller than $n!+2$ and let $p_2$ be the smallest prime greater than $n!+n$.  Then $p_2-p_1\ge n$ and $p_1,p_2$ are consecutive primes since none of the numbers $n!+2,n!+3,\dots, n!+n$ can be prime.

Answer (score 0):

Let $$S_n=\sum_{k=1}^n \frac {1}{k} $$
then

$$S_{2n}-S_n=\sum_{k=n+1}^{2n}\frac 1k $$

$$>n.\frac {1}{2n}=\frac 12$$

thus $(S_n) $ is not Cauchy and diverges

Comment: OP is considering the sum of reciprocals of primes.

Comment: But the OP's $S$ is surely the sum of the reciprocals of the primes (although he doesn't explicitly say so).